# How to secure an array field so Parse users can add objects without allowing malicious changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I understand the concept of only allowing Parse users to access to their own data. But how do you secure fields where you want users to have the ability to add or join, but not the ability to delete or make other changes?

Let's say you wanted users to have the ability to join a group or post in a thread. They would need write access to these objects, but wouldn't that open up potential malicious activity. How should I go about securing these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put this data in an object with 'public' read and master only write status, so no user can write directly to it, but any user you need to can read from it. The read status could also be by role, or specified users.

Now you create a cloud function to do the writing. That cloud function does whatever validation you need, checking the logged in user and any parameters that are passed and then updates the object, because it has access to `useMasterKey` so it can have the required privilege.